# Banach space norm induced by inner product; differentiability

Tags: analysis, derivatives, banach-spaces

> Let $\left( X,\left\| \cdot \right\| \right)$ be a Banach space where the norm $\left\| \cdot \right\|$ is induced by an inner product $\langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle$.
>   Let $f:X\times X\rightarrow X$, $f\left( x,y\right) =\langle y,x\rangle x$.

Show that f is differentiable in every point and calculate the total derivative.

I tried to show that all directional derivatives exist and are continuous but that didn‘t work. Is there a better way?

Comment: What's your definition of differentiable?  (There are more than 1 in Banach spaces, or even (I think) in Hilbert spaces.)  And "differentiable" where?  At the origin? Everywhere?

Comment: $f:V\rightarrow W$ is called differentiable in $a\in V$, if a linear mapping $L:V\rightarrow W$ and a function $R:V\rightarrow W$ exist, so that $f\left( x\right) =f\left( a\right) +L\left( x-a\right) +R\left( x\right)$ and $\lim _{v\rightarrow 0}\dfrac {R\left( x\right) }{\left\| x-a\right\| }=0$ for all $x\in V$.

Answer (score 0):

For Frechet differentiability, start by computing
$$
f(x+h,y+k)-f(x,y)=\langle y+k,x+h\rangle(x+h)-\langle y,x\rangle x=\dots
$$
and show it is "linear in $(h,k)$" + smaller.

Comment: I haven‘t learned about Frechet differentiability yet. Do you know of a way to show this with the definition of differentiability in the second comment under the post?

Comment: @Moe1234 I think you meant $\lim_{x \to a}$ not $\lim_{v \to 0}$. In this case, what you have written there is equivalent to Frechet differentiability

Comment: Yes i meant x->a. Thanks